# How to check if list item is in dictionary. If so, print the data associated with it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of names called `names`. I also have 2 dictionaries that contain a list of nested dictionaries that both have the key `names` and other data associated with the name. What I want to do is check that the name from the list is in one of the 2 dictionaries, if so, print the data associated only with that name. I can't find any of this stuff in the python docs

```
names = ['barry','john','george','sarah','lisa','james']

dict1 = {'results':[{'name':'barry','gpa':'2.9','major':'biology'},
                  {'name':'sarah','gpa':'3.2','major':'economics'},
                  {'name':'george','gpa':'2.5','major':'english'}]}

dict2 = {'staff':[{'name':'john','position':'Lecturer','department':'economics'},
                {'name':'lisa','position':'researcher','department':'physics'},
                {'name':'james','position':'tutor','department':'english'}]}

for x in names:
    if x in dict1:
        print gpa associated with the name
    elif x in dict2:
        print position associated with the name
```

Comment: Your data structures are far deeper than "2 dictionaries"...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams changed the question to reflect that I have list of nested dicts

Comment: Your dicts aren't terribly useful, having only one entry each. Any chance of using a more sensible data structure?

Comment: @MarkRansom This is just an example of the actual code I am working with. A dict of this exact structure is obtained from an outside source so I have little control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you're using for the two `dict`s isn't very optimal - each contains only a single element, which is a list of the relevant data for each person. If you can restructure those with a separate element per person using the name as a key, this becomes a trivial problem.

```
dict1 = {'barry': {'gpa':'2.9','major':'biology'},
         'sarah': {'gpa':'3.2','major':'economics'},
         'george': {'gpa':'2.5','major':'english'}}

dict2 = {'john': {'position':'Lecturer','department':'economics'},
         'lisa': {'position':'researcher','department':'physics'},
         'james': {'position':'tutor','department':'english'}}
```

Since it appears you can't get the data in this format, you'll have to convert it:

```
dict_results = dict((d['name'], d) for d in dict1[results])
if name in dict_results:
    print dict_results[name]['gpa']
```

Comment: Yeah that's something I can look into; but aside from creating a new dict, which would mean my having to get over my original problem, I can't see how this could work.

Comment: Yes that's a good alternative and exactly what I was looking for. I'm really struggling with dicts just can't get my head around the logic. Thanks for the informative post

Answer (score 1):

```
for _name in names:
    if _name in [person['name'] for person in dict1['results']]: pass
    elif _name in [person['name'] for person in dict2['staff']]:pass
```

something like that at least

Answer (score 1):

This should get you an idea:

```
for name in names:
  print name, ":"
  print "\t", [x for x in dict2["staff"] if x["name"] == name]
  print "\t", [x for x in dict1["results"] if x["name"] == name]
```

prints

```
barry :
  []
  [{'major': 'biology', 'name': 'barry', 'gpa': '2.9'}]
john :
  [{'department': 'economics', 'position': 'Lecturer', 'name': 'john'}]
  []
george :
  []
  [{'major': 'english', 'name': 'george', 'gpa': '2.5'}]
sarah :
  []
  [{'major': 'economics', 'name': 'sarah', 'gpa': '3.2'}]
lisa :
  [{'department': 'physics', 'position': 'researcher', 'name': 'lisa'}]
  []
james :
  [{'department': 'english', 'position': 'tutor', 'name': 'james'}]
  []
```

If you get this data from a database, you should probably rather work on the SQL frontier of the problem. A database is made for operations like that.

Comment: Thanks for that. No the data is being obtained from an API, returning json data converted to a python dict. This is the only way I can have it returned

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['barry','john','george','sarah','lisa','james']

dict1 = {'results':[{'name':'barry','gpa':'2.9','major':'biology'},
                  {'name':'sarah','gpa':'3.2','major':'economics'},
                  {'name':'george','gpa':'2.5','major':'english'}]}

dict2 = {'staff':[{'name':'john','position':'Lecturer','department':'economics'},
                {'name':'lisa','position':'researcher','department':'physics'},
                {'name':'james','position':'tutor','department':'english'}]}


import itertools

for x in itertools.chain(dict1['results'], dict2['staff']):
    for n in names:
        if n in x.values():
            print x
```

or the 2nd part could be:

```
ns = set(names)
for x in itertools.chain(dict1['results'], dict2['staff']):
    if x['name'] in ns:
        print x
```